# Firefox slow to restore windows on external 4k monitor

Tags: macos, display, performance, firefox

When I log in after my MacBook goes to sleep, Firefox is taking a long time to restore windows on an external 5k display (with a different DPI than the built-in display):

- first, windows are restored with smaller DPI,
- then they are visibly switched to a higher DPI,
- then windows are moved into the previous positions.

How can this process be sped up?

Is it an issue with Firefox or MacOS itself, or maybe it just cannot be helped?

Comment: Do you only experience this problem when using the external display? Does it happen when using your Mac?

Comment: Which MacBook model/year?  How big of a resolution difference between the built-in display and the external one?  What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: Yes, it's external display only. I don't see windows changing DPI if external display was not involved. MBP 2019, 13.4 (22F66), external display is LG UC-99, 3840x1600, but I have seen it on a number of other MacBooks and monitors.